# How to change input with a given value?

Tags: reactjs

How do I change input with a predefined value? To edit certain elements, the data in the value is obtained from the database, well, the idea is that when the user clicks on “Edit”, he has a window for accessing elements in which there was an old info

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const arr = { company: [{ companyName: "Apple" }] };

  const blockCreate = () => {
    return arr.company.map(project => (
      <input type="text" value={project.companyName} />
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{blockCreate()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Now nothing can be entered in input, but at the same time it outputs what is needed What to do?

Comment: Can you please explain, Are you trying to edit the value in the input?

Comment: Yes, I get input already with a certain value, in order to edit it

Answer (score 1):

To be able to modify your input value you need to hook it up to a value in the component `state`.

To do this in a functional component you need to use `useState` and assign a state variable `inputValue` and a function to update the value `updadeValue` to `useState`.

Then pass `inputValue` to the value for the input and `updadeValue` to the onchange event of the input.

I would modify the code to look like this,

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
    const arr = { company: [{ companyName: "Apple" }] };

    let [inputValue,updadeValue] = useState(project.companyName)

    const blockCreate = () => {
        return arr.company.map(project => (
            <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => updadeValue(e.target.value) } />
        ));
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>{blockCreate()}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `let [inputValue,updadeValue] = useState( arr.company[0].companyName)`

Comment: @Alex it is used within a map so `project` would be the current instance.

Comment: Try your code, You cant initialize state with `project` outside of map function.

Comment: @Alex you are right. I guess it may be a better idea to extract the whole input into it's own component. unless there is only one element in the array.